# Constrain parent trait to reference

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

I want to define a trait `Container` such that every implementor of this trait also needs to implement `IntoIterator`, with the caveat that the iteration ALWAYS only borrows the instance. If I understand correctly, I can implement `IntoIterator` using a pattern like this:

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a ContainerImpl
```

However, how can I specify that this needs to be implemented if a type implements `Container`, e.g.:

```
trait Container: &IntoIter ???
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a `where` clause to traits, too ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1ef54baa26ea7ed017219a9fccb69057&version=stable&backtrace=0version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
trait IterBorrow where for<'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator {}
impl IterBorrow for [i32] {} // legal
// impl IterBorrow for i32 {} // Illegal
```

However, it seems you currently need to reiterate this bound whenever you actually want to iterate, i.e., this function does not compile without the where clause:

```
fn foo<T: IterBorrow>(x: T) where for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator {
    for _ in &x {}
    for _ in &x {}
}
```

Comment: It makes sense, but the added boilerplate is quite unfortunate. Could you also point me to a doc that describes the use of for<> in the where clause? I couldn't find it anywhere..

Comment: @MrMobster They are called higher ranked trait bounds. There isn't a whole lot of documentation, but I found this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html